# Foreach loop repetition problem

Tags: php, foreach

This code gives four 4's and I only want one 4.. Can anyone identify the problem??

```
$value1 = "0";
$entries = array($var1_1a>$var1_1b, $var1_2a>$var1_2b, $var1_3a>$var1_3b,     
$var3_1a>$var3_1b, $var3_2a>$var3_2b, $var3_3a>$var3_3b);

if (count($entries) == 0)
    echo "0";
else foreach($entries as $entry)
 { 
if($entry > $value1)
{
    echo array_sum($entries);
}
}
```

Comment: if you `print_r($entries)` what do you see?

Comment: It isn't completely clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: instead of echo array_sum($entries), I put print_r($entries) and it gave me this: Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => ) Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 [5] => )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you even have a foreach loop? `echo array_sum($entries);` is independent of the values you're looping through.

This should be adequate:

```
$entries = array($var1_1a>$var1_1b, $var1_2a>$var1_2b, $var1_3a>$var1_3b,
  $var3_1a>$var3_1b, $var3_2a>$var3_2b, $var3_3a>$var3_3b);

echo array_sum($entries);
```

Comment: Glad to hear.  Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, though, so I can't be sure that I gave you the best answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
$value1 = "0";
$entries = array($var1_1a>$var1_1b, $var1_2a>$var1_2b, $var1_3a>$var1_3b,     
$var3_1a>$var3_1b, $var3_2a>$var3_2b, $var3_3a>$var3_3b);

if (count($entries) == 0)
    echo "0";
else foreach($entries as $entry)
 { 
if($entry > $value1)
{
    echo array_sum($entries);
     break; //I think it will checking condition repeatedly 
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah it was the break thingy thanxx you are the sexiest person ever

Comment: So why even have the loop then?  Just take the whole loop out.